# PostgreSQL Как получить список серверов в командной строке?

Tags: postgresql

Как мне с помощю командной строки получить этот список серверов и делать простые операции (создать, удалить) с ними?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понял это не foreign servers так как:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Windows, PostgreSQL 11.1 on x86_64-pc-mingw64, compiled by gcc.exe (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project) 4.9.2, 64-bit

Comment: Когда вы в командной строчке ( psql) вы уже приконектились к конкретному серверу, а он ничего не знает о других.

Answer (score 0):

pgAdmin - это клиент к базе, а не база. Клиент может подключаться к разным серверам. Для удобства пользователя клиент может сохранять список серверов, к которым подключается пользователь. Но этот список не имеет ровно никакого отношения к самой СУБД. Это фича клиента и только его.

Если вы хотите изменять этот список как-то автоматически, смотрите документацию к клиентскому приложению. Где-то например [здесь](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/export_import_servers.html), как раз экспорт и импорт этого списка.

Если вы хотите управлять запущенными экземплярами PostgreSQL (кластерами в терминологии PostgreSQL) - то это не имеет никакого отношения в свою очередь к клиентским приложениям. Начните с соответствующего [раздела документации](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/runtime.html), для старта нового кластера вам необходимо его инициализировать из `initdb` (либо из `basebackup`), внести изменения в конфигурацию (в частности скорей всего потребуется поменять порт), запустить. Для удаления соответственно остановить процессы и удалить `datadir`